# How to solve IE6 selectbox flicker problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I am experiencing a strange IE6 problem. I have an ajax request which refreshes a part of my page. However after the DOM injection the select boxes are disappearing and after a fraction of a seccond they appear again.

Is there any way to prevent this? or solve ?

I am using jQuery for the ajax part.

Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code so we can see exactly how you've implemented this.

Answer (score 0):

I remember hitting the same problem once. Try setting the width (`style="width:100px"`) or `size` attribute of the `<select>`.